# Permission Denied error in vbscript while running wshShell

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

When I run this code, it prints a "Permission Denied" error every time. The error code is `800a0046` and the code which generates this error is as below.

```
Sub Delay( seconds )
    Dim wshShell, strCmd
    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    strCmd = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMSPEC% /C (PING.EXE -n " & ( seconds + 1 ) & " localhost >NUL 2>&1)" )
    wshShell.Run strCmd, 0, 1
    Set wshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

on the 4th line it throws the error

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' 
Permission denied
```

Can anybody please provide a solution to how and where to set the required permission.

Comment: How did you test it on your side ?. For me works !  with vbscript !

Comment: It works at my end as well but on other environment, consider as production it doesn't works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug ASP permission problems with WScript.Shell object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897293/how-to-debug-asp-permission-problems-with-wscript-shell-object)